# Implementing Dependency Injection in a Controller to create loosly couple system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a HomeController and a Referrence of a type-class.If I create a new object of the class it works fine for me. But I dont want to create new object in the Controller instead I want to pass a referrence of the class through the HomwController's Constructor.Here is my code. I need to implement DI here.

```
//private readonly UnitOfWork<Student> _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<Student>();
    private readonly UnitOfWork<Student> _unitOfWork;

    //TODO ??
    public HomeController(UnitOfWork<Student> unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View(_unitOfWork.GenericRepository.GetAll());
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking ASP.NET MVC ?

I have been working with Ninject for some time now, and am very happy with it! Take a look at the sample app in this repository to get an idea on how to use it in ASP.NET MVC 3:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/tree/master/mvc3

To expand a bit on the reply, here's a code snippet from where I set up the Ninject bindings

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>).To(typeof(UnitOfWork<>));
```

And my controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<Student> uowStudent;
    public MyController(IUnitOfWork<Student> uowStudent) {
        this.uowStudent = uowStudent;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do, is make sure any arguments in the constructor for the UnitOfWork class are also bound in the kernel.

Comment: I know about Ninject. You did not get my point. I want to create new object using DI @SteenT

Comment: In Global.asax i tried by the following code `<pre>private void SetupDependencyInjection()
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<UnitOfWork<Student>>().To<UnitOfWork<Student>>();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }</pre>`

Comment: logical f - wtf  `kernel.Bind<UnitOfWork<Student>>().To<UnitOfWork<Student>>();`. the idea of DI is that you use interfaces and inject concrete classes into the ctor. you seem to have misunderstood the concept. you need to identify a: why you want to use it if you don't understand it and b: what your perceived benefit is going to be if you don't have concrete classes that use some sort of IStudent, IUnitOfWork (preferably IRepository instead) interface. i'm baffled :)

Comment: OK I am new to DI and your reaction is weired :/. Using Istudent will not help me, I am sure about that and I will use UnitOfWork<T> for accessing various repository. The main problem i stated above. I repeat I dont want to create a new object in my controller. Got that? @jim tollan

Comment: Logical -sure I got it, but what I'm saying is that I'm baffled at you trying to inject a like for like concrete class, there's no benefit or logic to that. the idea of DI is that you have a loosley coupled set of interfaces with concrete implementations injected into your controller (or service class) ctor. if my reaction is weird, it's because i'm scottish !! - we stand no nonesense!! :-)

Comment: @jimtollan Yeah. The logic behind posting the question was very much simple,that is i am a newbie in DI and asp.net. If I could solve my problem than i would not ask in this site.Most people ask here if they face any problem.right? I think there is no such kind of rules and regulations about posting questions here. And I think you are an educated person, so whether you are scottish or american of african or bla bla bla.... I dont give a damn man. Educated person should have a standard to communicate over the internet with the people. Nations should not come into this. Thanks :)

Comment: Here's a snippet of code from my DI setup (using Ninject): kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<>>().To<UnitOfWork<>>(); Then you can do you controller like so: public class MyController : Controller { public MyController(IUnitOfWork<Student> uowStudent) {} }

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to use dependency injection, you'll have to go through a third party dependency injection container - NInject or Unity for example among many others (or building your own if you are looking for some challenge).

Second, your HomeController should take an abstract unit of work type (interface or abstract class) as a parameter. You are actually using a concrete type in your HomeController constructor which is not how things should work in a dependency injection world (when using "Constructor Injection", your dependency container is in charge of providing the concrete implementation for the abstraction, based on container configuration).

Third your `UnitOfWork<Student>` does not make a lot of sense. A `Repository<Student>` would make some sense, but a Unit Of Work is not working on a single "Type" but rather on a "collection" of different data sets (a unit of work is potentially working on a collection of repositories). What would make sense here is to specify a parameter `IUnitOfWork unitOfWork` in your HomeController constructor, and configure your depency container to pass in a concrete `UnitOfWork` object on which you can get your `Repository<Student>` do operations on it in your action method (and potentially on other repositories accessed from the UnitOfWork object) and then Commit all modifcations by calling the associated method on the `UnitOfWork` object.

You should make some searches arround NInject use with ASP.NET MVC3 and also take a look at EntityFramework if you are dealing with UnitOfWork and Repository patterns (and if data is backed by a DB).

**EDIT**

In reaction to your comment dealing with `(IUnitOfWork<Student>` and `IUnitOfWork<Course>`).

As I said before, it does not make a lot of sense :

A UnitOfWork can be grossly seen as a "container" of repositories, giving access to these repositories and coordinating actions (like commiting all the changes) on these repositories. You should rather have an abstract non generic type `IUnitOfWork`, providing access to generic repositories such as `IRepository<Student>` or `IRepository<Course>`, and also containing a Commit method which would commit to DB (or file, or memory or whatever the unitofwork/repository implementation is targeting to persist data).

This way instead of injecting an `IRepository<Student>` and/or `IRepository<Course>` in your controller constructor (or if your controller needs to work on 10 different repositories, well, pass 10 parameters :S), you just accept a single parameter of abstract type IUnitOfWork (the concrete instance being injected by the DI container), and then any action method can work on any set of repository by getting them from the UnitOfWork, and once it has done all the changes, it can call Commit on the unitOfWork which will take care of comming all the modifications that have been done in the repository.

That's the theory and the general idea.

Now more specifically about DI in ASP.NET MVC, the more common way (there are other ways) of "plumbing" the DI container is to create a class inheriting from `IDependencyResolver` making use of the DI container to resolve types, and in `Application_Start` call `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` whith an instance of this class.
This way, when ASP.NET MVC is asked to create a controller (end user request), it will go through this depency resolver to ask for an instance of the controller, and this dependency resolver will turn to the DI container to create an instance of the controller by taking care of all needed injection.
You should take a look on the website / forums of your specific DI container as they all show ways to plumb it with ASP.NET MVC.

This is just a very high overview, there are a lot of tricky details, but that's the gross idea.

**EDIT2**

Just posted an article (my first one) on my blog to explain how to correctly use the Repository and UnitOfWork patterns in an ASP.NET MVC project.

http://codefizzle.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/correct-use-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: +1 - almost to a 'T' exactly what I said in the comments to SteenT's answer. great minds - and fools :-)

Comment: I am trying to make a generic type of repository. Like If I call **UnitOfWork<Student>** It will call the student repository and I know UnitOfWork is a collection of repositories and I am trying to modify it, making it generic. Like If I make an object of **UnitOfWork<Course>** it will provide a CourseRepository to me. @darkey . If I am wrong tell me. Thanks